# click an image and add class to it but when selectin other one remove the class

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have multiple images which I can select from a carousell. These images are rendered from a map function like this:

```
 {imagenesProductos.map((img) => {
                  if (img) {
                    console.log(img);
                    return (
                      <SwiperSlide className="">
                        <Image onClick={e => clickedImage(e)} className="product" src={img} width={100} height={100} alt='productImage' />
                      </SwiperSlide>
                    )
                  }
  })}
```

When I click the image I have a method that just console logs the src of the image.

```
  const clickedImage = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.src)
  }
```

What I want to do is to add a class to the selected image and remove it when I select another one. I am using styled components.

I hope you can help me! Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have a state that holder an identifier of this specific selected image. For example:

```
const [selectedPath,setSelectedPath]=useState('');
```

Than, in the `map` you can add a condition with this state, and use the `className`  where you need.

```
 {imagenesProductos.map((img) => {
                  if (img) {
                    console.log(img);
                    return (
                      <SwiperSlide className="">
                        <Image onClick={clickedImage} className=`product ${img===selectedPath?"selected":""}` src={img} width={100} height={100} alt='productImage' />
                      </SwiperSlide>
                    )
                  }
  })}
```

And the clickImage function should be:

```
 const clickedImage = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.src);
    setSelectedPath(e.target.src);
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a state to track clicked images. if the current image in the map is a selected image then you can add a class `active` or anything you like. I am using index as key as list of image wouldn’t change often I suppose.
Following  is the sample code for it.

```
const [curImageIndex, setCurImageIndex] = useState(null);
  const clickedImage = (index) => {
    setCurImageIndex(index);
  };

  return (
    <>
      {magenesProductos.map((img, index) => {
        if (img) {
          console.log(img);
          return (
            <SwiperSlide
              className={`product ${curImageIndex === index? 'active' : ''}`}
              key={index}
            >
              <Image
                onClick={() => clickedImage(index)}
                className="product"
                src={img}
                width={100}
                height={100}
                alt="productImage"
              />
            </SwiperSlide>
          );
        }
      })}
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a single state to hold the currently selected image. Filter `imagenesProductos` before mapping. Compare the currently mapped `img` to the stored `selectedImage` state to conditionally add the other class to the image.

```
const [selectedImage, setSelectedImage] = React.useState(null);

...

const clickedImage = (e) => {
  const { src } = e.target;
  console.log(src);
  setSelectedImage(src);
}

...

{imagenesProductos
  .filter(img => img)
  .map((img) => {
    console.log(img);
    return (
      <SwiperSlide className="">
        <Image
          onClick={clickedImage}
          className={["product", selectedImage === img ? "newClass" : ""].join(" ")}
          src={img}
          width={100}
          height={100}
          alt='productImage'
        />
      </SwiperSlide>
    );
  }
})}
```